# Linux commands to output part of input file's name and line count

Tags: bash

What Linux commands would you use successively, for a bunch of files, to count the number of lines in a file and output to an output file with part of the corresponding input file as part of the output line. So for example we were looking at file `LOG_Yellow` and it had 28 lines, the the output file would have a line like this (`Yellow` and `28` are tab separated):

```
Yellow    28
```

Comment: Do all the files start with LOG_?

Comment: Yes. I think using a combination of awk and wc -l would be best.

Comment: I am at a loss as to why this isn't closed as belonging on superuser (or serverfault, if you consider all linux questions to be server-related).

Comment: @rmeador: it's bash programming.

Comment: @biznez: you need to put additional information into the post, you cannot just leave it as a comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
wc -l [filenames] | grep -v " total$" | sed s/[prefix]//
```

The wc -l generates the output in almost the right format; grep -v removes the "total" line that wc generates for you; sed strips the junk you don't want from the filenames.

Answer (score 2):

```
wc -l * | head --lines=-1 > output.txt
```

produces output like this:

```
linecount1 filename1
linecount2 filename2
```

I think you should be able to work from here to extend to your needs.

**edit**: since I haven't seen the rules for you name extraction, I still leave the full name. However, unlike other answers I'd prefer to use `head` rather then `grep`, which not only should be slightly faster, but also avoids the case of filtering out files named `total*`.

**edit2** (having read the comments): the following does the whole lot:

```
wc -l * | head --lines=-1 | sed s/LOG_// | awk '{print $2 "\t" $1}' > output.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

`wc -l *| grep -v " total"`
send

*28 Yellow*

You can reverse it if you want (awk, if you don't have space in file names)
`wc -l *| egrep -v " total$" | sed s/[prefix]//
| awk '{print $2 " " $1}'`

Comment: Add Sbodd's call to `sed` and this is the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Short of writing the script for you:

- 'for' for looping through your files.
- 'echo -n' for printing the current file
- 'wc -l' for finding out the line count
- And dont forget to redirect
  ('>' or '>>') your results to your
  output file